# Changing Java EE server from GlassFish to Tomcat

Tags: jsf, tomcat, netbeans, glassfish

I developed an applications using Netbeans with JSF, JPA and Primefaces and works fine in GlassFish server. I wanted to deploy in Tomcat server. I changed the server through properties, but the project can not be clean and built successfully. How can I change the server properly?

Details :

Netbeans 7.3

GlassFish 3.1

Tomcat 7

I opened the project with Netbeans.
Right click the project and the GlassFish is selected as the Server.
Right clicked and select Clean and Build. It comes as successful.
Right clicked and select Run. The web applications starts running perfectly.

Then I stopped GlassFish and Started Tomcat through Netbeans servers window.

The righted clicked and select Project Properties. Changed the server to Tomcat.
Right click and select Clean and Build
And this error comes. No Dist folder creation as well.

The stack trace is listed below.

```
An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent not found
at     org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:342)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:333)
at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:56)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1153)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:930)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.JavacTask.execute(JavacTask.java:145)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:283)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:541)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent not found
C:\Users\Buddhika\Documents\ho\HealthOffice\nbproject\build-impl.xml:887: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Buddhika\Documents\ho\HealthOffice\nbproject\build-impl.xml:309: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Glassfish is a full fledged Java EE web application server and ships with among others JSF already bundled. Tomcat is a barebones JSP/Servlet container and doesn't ship with anything else from Java EE bundled. When deploying a JSF web application to Tomcat, the developer is required to provide the JSF libraries in either the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` or Tomcat's `/lib` by itself.

This exception, which is trying to tell you that it can't find a JSF-specific class in order to compile your code, indicates that you haven't done that. [Download](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) JSF 2.x and drop the `javax.faces.jar` file in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` or Tomcat's `/lib` and you should be all set.

Comment: I downloaded javax.faces-2.1.14.jar and put it in the lib folder of the Tomcat server and restarted the server. The same error as previously. Then I kept the jar in that lib folder, but added the same file through the project properties. That resulted in bringing several errors in the existing classes, for example, all the below imports were not recognized.                                            import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.Query;
    import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
    import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

Comment: So your initial problem is solved and you advanced to the next problem. Those classes are from JPA. This is also not bundled in Tomcat. You'd need to install JPA in Tomcat yourself. Why exactly are you falling back from Glassfish to Tomcat without even considering if Tomcat actually supports your webapp? Can't you better consider TomEE?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I could continue with configuring Tomcat with JPA as well as you instructed. I reconsidered to stick with GlassFish. I only wanted to go to Tomcat as the virtual hosting provider gave me a hosting plan with Tomcat. So I though I will stick to GlassFish and I will look for a virtual server provider which has GlassFish hosting. As it was not freely available, I though of going to Tomcat. I have also not heard of TomEE, but now will read on that for my knowledge, yet as You said, I have no reason to give up GlassFish. Thank you again for your effort to explain everything.

Answer (score 0):

Q: but the project can not be clean and built successfully.

A: Your error message indicates a *runtime* error, doesn't it?

Q: Exactly what is failing?  Tomcat?  Trying to compile your .war?  Simply trying to open it in your IDE?

Q: If compiler, then how are you compiling?  From your IDE?  From an ANT script?  Something else?

Q: Are you using an IDE?  What kind (e.g. Netbeans) and what version?

Q: What platform?

ALSO:

See if this link might be applicable:

- [Slingshot Yourself into JSF 2.0 Development using Tomcat 7 & the JDK](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=61864)

Comment: Edited to Add details  you request to question. Thanks

Comment: This isn't an answer at all. This is more appropriate as a comment on the question.

Comment: @Buddhika Ariyaratne - thank you for your update.  Please read my link, and please make sure to install JSF (the cause of the error message you posted).  And whatever other components you might be missing from Tomcat.  This link might also help: http://uaihebert.com/?p=1440  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. That configuration seems very complex. I will stuck with GlassFish. I only wanted to shift as the virtual server provider offered Tomcat as they have already installed it. But They do not have GlassFish hosting. I will find a hosting service with GlassFish. Thanks all

Comment: Q: Isn't it possible to install GlassFish on the provider's VPS?

Comment: I have no experience in virtual servers, just attempting for the first time. It seems the charges are expensive for GlassFish. Someone with Virtual server will comment on that.